# How to integrate sign in with apple in iOS 12 or earlier?

Tags: xcode, ios12, apple-sign-in

My app was rejected due to a third-party login service.
So I've implemented Sign in with Apple for iOS 13.
Problem is how to provide backward compatibility for iOS 12 or earlier.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it only works (for iOS12 and below) if I avoid importing **CryptoKit** for the **sha256** encryption. Instead of using the sha256 function provided by CryptoKit you can extend the String class adding a sha256 function by importing **CommonCrypto**.

You can check the code in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60987888/2025766

Importing CryptoKit on iOS12 and below will crash your app with this error:

```
Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CryptoKit.framework/CryptoKit"
```

when the app starts.

I also tried to use **#if canImport(CryptoKit)** for conditional import and set **-weak_framework CryptoKit** in Other Linker Flags but still crashing for iOS12. So far avoid CryptoKit is the only solution that I found.

Answer (score 0):

Add `-weak_framework Cryptokit` in **Other Linker Flags** of respective target's build settings.

Answer (score 0):

Check apple official page [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js/incorporating_sign_in_with_apple_into_other_platforms). You need to go out and open a webpage and then comeback to the application with error (user cancel) or success with the scope you've requested.

Answer (score 0):

Apple nowadays recommends it's [`Sign in with Apple JS`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js) in combination with their [REST API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api).

You basically create an own button that uses the Apple Marketing resource images and then call their REST API to initiate the authorization flow. For the initial log-in window, you can use a `WKWebView` and handle the callback URL via the successful / failed redirect.